# Evaluating a complex integral (Hints please)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am supposed to be able to show that, given

$f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1r\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{d\theta}{re^{i\theta}+z}dr$

then $f(z)=\overline{z}$ for $|z|<1$ and $f(z)=1/z$ if $|z|\geq1$.

(This is taken from Chapter 10 in Rudin's Complex analysis text.)

Basically, I'm not sure where to start thinking. I've tried manipulating the integral into something able to use Cauchy's Theorem, but that fell apart rather quickly. Plugging the inner integral into Mathematica I can see that it is supposed to evaluate to $\frac{2\pi}{z}$ (which doesn't seem to lead me to the result that is desired). Any suggestions, tips, or tricks would be very helpful! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $|z| < 1$, split the integral in $r$ to $\int_{0}^{|z|}$ and $\int_{|z|}^{1}$. When $r < |z|$, you can show the inner integral to be $\frac{2\pi}{z}$ as you claim. Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{2\pi}{z}\int_{0}^{|z|}r \,dr = ...
\end{equation}
will lead to what you want. You also want to dispense with the $\int_{|z|}^{1}r\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[...]$ term.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
f(0)=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\left[\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta\right]\,dr=-\frac{e^{i\theta}}{i\pi}\Big|_{-\pi}^\pi=0.
$$
If $z\ne 0$, we set
$$
\xi=re^{i\theta}.
$$
Then
$$
d\xi=ire^{i\theta}d\theta=i\xi d\theta,
$$
and
\begin{eqnarray}
f(z)&=&\frac1\pi\int_0^1r\left[\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{d\theta}{re^{i\theta}+z}\right]\,dr=\frac1\pi\int_0^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{i\xi(\xi+z)}\right]\,dr\\
&=&\frac{1}{i\pi z}\int_0^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\left(\frac{1}{\xi}-\frac{1}{\xi+z}\right)\,d\xi\right]\,dr\\
&=&\frac{1}{i\pi z}\int_0^1r\left[2\pi i-\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr\\
&=&\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{i\pi z}\int_0^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr
\end{eqnarray}
If $|z|\ge 1$, we have

$$
\int_0^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\int_0^{1-\varepsilon} r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z} \, \mbox{ for }\, |z|\ge 1.
$$
For $0<|z|<1$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr&=&\underbrace{\int_0^{|z|}r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr}_{0}+\int_{|z|}^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr\\
&=&\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\int_{|z|+\varepsilon}^1r\left[\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{d\xi}{\xi+z}\right]\,dr=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\int_{|z|+\varepsilon}^12\pi ir\,dr\\
&=&i\pi(1-|z|^2).
\end{eqnarray}
We then deduce that
$$
f(z)=\frac1z-\frac{i\pi(1-|z|^2)}{i\pi z}=\frac{|z|^2}{z}=\bar{z} \quad \forall 0<|z|<1
$$
Hence
$$
f(z)=\begin{cases}
\bar{z} &\mbox{ if }\, |z|<1\\
\frac{1}{z} &\mbox{ if }\, |z|\ge 1
\end{cases}.
$$